# get attributes of event.target's parents

Tags: jquery, parent

I have the following HTML code

```
<html>
    <head>
         <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="form" id="form1">
            First name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname">
            <br>
            Last name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to obtain a list of attributes of the parent of a clicked element. 
e.g If I click on the input tag, "class" and "id" should be returned as those are the attributes of the "form" tag.

So far I managed to obtain the attributes of the element being clicked using:

```
$(event.target.attributes)
```

However nothing is being returned when I try to do the same for the parent element. Is something wrong in my code please?

```
$($(event.target).parents().eq(0).attributes)
```

Comment: If you want to get the parent, you can use $($(event.target).parent())

Comment: Additionally, what you are doing is in a way correct (though not ideal way of doing it), just get rid of extra $(). It should be - $(event.target).parents().eq(0).attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem using

```
$(event.target).parents().eq(0).each(function() {
    $.each(this.attributes, function() {
        if(this.specified) {
            alert(this.name, this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will iterate over the parent i.e. form element

```
$.each($(event.target).parent().attributes, function() {
    // this.attributes is not a plain object, but an array
    // of attribute nodes, which contain both the name and value
    if(this.specified) {
      console.log(this.name, this.value);
    }
  });
```

Also, as suggested by fellow members, you should use **$(this)** in place of **$(event.target)**

Comment: Thank you. Although your answer didn't really work for me, it put me on the right direction in my investigation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually in the event handler, why not directly refer to the element using `this` ??

```
$(this).parent().attr("class");
```

This is applicable for immediate parents, however if you're trying address someone over the immediate parent, you can use `$(this).parents` : ,

```
$(this).parents("form").attr("class");
```

Edit : Since you're trying to fetch the list of attributes and see if a particular attribute exists, you can use

```
$(this).parents("form")[0].attributes
```

This will return you a NamedNodeMap..

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited the question as I believe that it was unclear. Basically I am not trying to get the value of the class attribute (that will come later). At this point I want to know that the parent has a class attribute and an id attribute.

Comment: $(this).parents("td")[0] does not make sense here :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Edited the answer. Copied from something i was trying in the browser itself :D.